# Some basic questions about V=L

Tags: set-theory

I am reading through Robert Wolf's *A Tour Through Mathematical Logic*, which is excellent, but very quick (for a self-studying beginner, like me, at least).  I wanted to follow up on four points.

(1) The definition of the Constructible Hierarchy appeals to the meta-logical notion of satisfaction.  How does one define this in the language of set theory?

(2) In the proof that the Pairing Axiom if absolute for $L$, Wolf says that because $L$ is transitive, $\mathrm{Pairing}^L$ reduces to:
$\forall x,y \in L : {x,y} \in L$.  I do not understand the relevance of transitivity here.

(3) Wolf remarks that $L_{\omega + 1}$ is countable since $L_\omega$ is.  But this confuses me.  Can't we prove in ZF that $V_{\omega + 1}$ is uncountable?  If so, why can't we conclude that $V_{\omega + 1}$ is not $L_{\omega + 1}$, so $\neg (V=L)$?

(4) Since $L$ contains all the ordinals, $L$ must be uncountable.  Is the first uncountable level of $L$ $V_{\omega_1}$? (If not, why not?)

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: These two threads might be helpful also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151677/gch-constructible-universe-and-von-neumann-universe/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114637/contrasting-constructible-universe-and-von-neumann-universe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re (3): $V_{\omega +1}$ and $L_{\omega +1}$ are two different things, even though $V_{\omega}=L_{\omega}.$

$V_{\omega +1}$ is the power set of $V_{\omega}.$ The definition of $L_{\omega +1}$ in terms of $L_{\omega}$ is quite different.

Re (1) and(4): $L$ is a definable proper class, not a set. That is, we do have a formula $f$ such that $x\in L$ is an abbreviation for $f[x].$ The formula $f$ is just inconveniently long to write it out more than once in a lifetime. $L$ cannot be a set ,otherwise $L\cap ON=ON$ would also be a set.(ON is the definable class of ordinals.

$|L_{\omega_1}|=\omega_1.$ When $a<\omega_1$ then $L_a$ is countable. So $|L_{\omega_1}|=|\cup_{a<\omega_1}L_a|\leq \omega_1.$ But $\omega_1\subset L_{\omega_1}$ so $|L_{\omega_1}|\geq \omega_1.$

Be careful to distinguish $\omega_1$ and $(\omega_1)^L.$

Comment: The easiest and clearest description of L that I have seen is in Lectures In Set Theory (various authors. Edited by Morley)

Comment: OK, I'll check it out.